# Javascript/HTML - Problema al hacer un buscador abierto

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando hacer un buscador en javascript que recibe las variables de una base de datos desde PHP y MYSQLI y necesito realizar una busqueda de todos los resultados similares a la palabra introducida de tal forma que me inserte en mi html los resultados similares.

En resumen, en Javascript tengo un array de variables y cuando el usuario llama la funcion para buscar (desde el html), necesito que el Javascript agregue el resultado mas cercano a la palabra introducida y los resultados mas similares(estos resultados similares pueden tener menos caracteres que el original e incluso mas caracteres que el similar) Por Ejemplo:

-La palabra que el usuario introduce es "Escritor"

-La lista de resultados que tengo incluye:
["Escritor","Escrito","Escritura","Escrupuloso","Estudio"]

-Deberia mostrar como resultado "Escritor" y como resultado similares "Escrito", "Escritura"

Comment: Tienes que hacer un for de tu array usando .contains, si esta lo agregas

Comment: [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) es tu amigo

Comment: Saludos. Por lo regular las expresiones que uses para la búsqueda será la usada para buscar coincidencias; para lo que pides tendrás que crear como una base/grupo de palabras donde colocar aquellas que deberá junto con esa; así al buscar la palabras obtendrás aquellas que tu relacionaste y esas serán realmente tu criterio de búsqueda.

Comment: @NicolasOñate En el caso de tener asi:


`var a = ["Escritor", "Escrito", "Escritura", "Escrupuloso", "Estudio"];`

`var buscar = "Escritor";`

Y necesito que me muestre como resultados:

Escritor, Escrito y Escritura.
.Como seria la forma correcta de usar el .find()?

Comment: @RobertoLeOr Considere hacer eso, pero el problema es que al tener demasiadas se haria un lio tener que hacer las conexiones entre cada palabra, y por eso pase a preguntar para saber si hay alguna solucion mas practica

Comment: @Jose desde SQL con el `WHERE` usando `LIKE` sustituyendo las vocales por `_` y colocando en los extremos `%` sería similar, pero al grado que pide (algo asi como) `Escritor=Escrupuloso` yo desconozco como lograrlo salvo de la forma que antes mencione. Salvo para la búsqueda uses la mitad de la palabra que te proporcionen para la búsqueda; pero `Escritor=Estudio` no se lograría ya que solo coinciden las 1ras 2 letras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo tengo asi en alguna pagina.
Esto esta dentro de un `for`.

```
if(array[x].toUpperCase().indexOf(PALABRA_BUSCADA.toUpperCase()) != -1){
   alert(array[x]);
}
```

espero te ayude

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. En parte cumple lo que pido, pero este metodo creo que no serviria para el caso de los resultados mas similares, ya que el indexOf() busca el texto que contenga exactamente ese string y en este caso, los resultados similares tienen ciertas variaciones... Al recorrer el array y ejecutar esa condicional solo se obtendria el resultado de "Escritor" y no reconoceria a los de "Escritura" y "Escrito"

Comment: usalo con substring

Comment: sino puedes usar .contains, lo acabo de ver ahora